# Update serialized field without serializing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If you mark a field with "serialize", is there still a way to update the field directly, without it running through the serialization code?  I have the serialization form I want, and I do not want it re-serialized.

The use-case for this is that I am writing a migration to move from YAML serialization of a data column to JSON.  I have overridden the serialize method to do JSON serialization instead of YAML.  In my down migration, I need to go back from JSON to YAML, and I don't want the YAML re-serialized as JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by creating your own SQL update query. A simple way to do this is with `update_all`.

For example, if you have a model called `Ball` that has a serialized attribute `colors`:

```
Ball.where(id: ball_id).update_all colors: "arbitrary string"
```

This will generate the following query:

```
UPDATE "balls" SET "colors" = 'arbitrary string' WHERE "balls"."id" = 123
```

Just be careful as this does not instantiate your model so it bypasses validations, filters, etc. It is equivalent to calling `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.send`.

Comment: Just a caution: I'm finding this doesn't work (on Rails 4.2) because `update_all` serializes the argument. So in the example above, it will execute `"colors" = '\"arbitrary string\"'`. I wanted to store a JSON-serialised field with update_all, so I simply ran `Ball.update_all color_map: {}` which works fine. Whereas `Ball.update_all color_map: "{}"` would incorrectly make the value a string instead.